# C# - Visual Studio Not able to clean textbox after IF Statement

Tags: c#, textbox

I am making a very simple program. Need some help clearing out a textbox after performing a search. I have used the `cboPrograms.Text = string.Empty;` but I must not be putting it in the right place. After I choose an option it will not clear.

```
private void cboPrograms_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cboPrograms.Text == "MFValidation")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla\\Mozilla.exe");
        }
        else if (cboPrograms.Text == "Add/Remove Programs")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\AddRemove\\addremove.exe");
            cboPrograms.Text = string.Empty;
        }


        {
            cboPrograms.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because cboPrograms is not a TextBox but a ComboBox. (Text boxes do not have a  `SelectedIndexChanged` event.)

To clear a combo box you do this:

```
cboPrograms.SelectedIdex = -1;
```

Also, reading the text of the combo box is not a good practice. You should have a collection of objects bound to the combo box. Get the selected object by calling `SelectedItem` and then working with the object's properties. The text you're seeing should just be a textual representation of the object. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info.

Comment: +0. Good point on "TextBox" actually meaning "ComboBox"... But it still does not explain behavior OP sees - [ComboBox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): "Setting the Text property to null or an empty string ("") sets the SelectedIndex to -1"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Hmm. I've tried to reset a ComboBox with `string.Empty` and see no mention of the behavior you're describing in the class' documentation. Actually, if it did behave that way then the OP should end up in an infinite loop since the combo box' index would be getting changed from the handler.

Comment: I think you are looking at WPF one [Combobox.Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) while I assumed that OP using WinForms... There is good chance you are right so +1.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an `else` statement before this code

```
   {
       cboPrograms.Text = string.Empty;
   }
```

Comment: Why? If you add `else` it will clean textbox *less often*... It already should be happening all the time... Most likely OP get an exception in one of `Start` calls and this code simply never executed...

Comment: Then it should not had `cboPrograms.Text = string.Empty;` in the `else if` and also the curly brackets would not be needed.

Comment: Indeed - I'm not saying your suggestion is wrong, but it will not change behavior of OP's sample. It is hard to say if intention is to clear textbox all the time or except first choice looking at the code... Note that adhering to DRY or removing unnecessary code may not be main concern for someone who uses magic values (like `"MFValidation"`) in the code - so duplication may be semi-intentional.

Comment: I see your point. I think the question is wrong or incomplete.